# android XML tag called eat-comment, what is its use?

Tags: android, xml, tags, comments

Noticed while looking through the android sdk of a tag like this:

```
<eat-comment/>
```

What is it used for?  A reference example for it is here:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`<eat-comment/>` is used to suppress comment lines from the documentation output.

You can read a little bit about it, with examples, here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2888524e03896831f487e5dee63f18f1c33c0115/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml

Comment: How to see document for custom attr ?
Can you please help me.